# Dovecot service doesn't start

Tags: mysql, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I follow these steps to install a postfix/dovecot/mysql mail service: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c2q64gndb9dwpmm/Postfix__Dovecot.pdf

When i need to restart a dovecot service and view "mail.log" file. Dovecot dont print any string in this file.

And when i try to restart the service. System print me this:

```
stop: Unknown instance:
dovecot start/running, process 32057
```

But when i execute "top" the 32057 process id doesn't exist.

For more information. When i try to restart postfix service:

```
 * Stopping Postfix Mail Transport Agent postfix                                                                                                                                                                                                                              /usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        [ OK ]
* Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent postfix                                                                                                                                                                                                                              postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
```

dovecot -F print me this:

```
doveconf: Warning: NOTE: You can get a new clean config file with: doveconf -n > dovecot-new.conf
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:1: 'imaps' protocol is no longer necessary, remove it
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:1: 'pop3s' protocol is no longer necessary, remove it
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:5: ssl_cert_file has been replaced by ssl_cert = <file
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:6: ssl_key_file has been replaced by ssl_key = <file
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:8: namespace private {} has been replaced by namespace { type=private }
doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf line 19: Unknown setting: global_script_path
```

This is my conf:

```
protocols = imap imaps pop3 pop3s
log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
mail_location = maildir:/home/vmail/%d/%n/Maildir

ssl_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem

namespace private {
        separator = .
        prefix = INBOX.
        inbox = yes
}

protocol lda {
        log_path = /home/vmail/dovecot-deliver.log
        auth_socket_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
        postmaster_address = postmaster@ieslasgalletas.org
        mail_plugins = sieve
        global_script_path = /home/vmail/globalsieverc
}

protocol pop3 {
        pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
}

auth default {
        user = root

        passdb sql {
                args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
        }

        userdb static {
                args = uid=5000 gid=5000 home=/home/vmail/%d/%n allow_all_users=yes
        }

        socket listen {
                master {
                        path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
                        mode = 0600
                        user = vmail
                }

                client {
                        path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
                        mode = 0660
                        user = postfix
                        group = postfix
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: you are obviously following some old guide with old configuration parameters. Remove `imaps` and `pop3s` from `dovecot.conf` at `line 1`. Also replace `ssl_cert_file` with `ssl_cert` at `line 5`.

Comment: Can you also paste into your question the output from `ls -l /etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem`, just to clear up any doubt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run Dovecot as a foreground process, does it output any errors?

To run Dovecot in the foreground:
`dovecot -F`

Comment: i updated my question